# Callback function to jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, callback

I doubt about the "call" function in Javascript. I have this jQuery plugin:

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        method1 : function( settings, callback ) { 
            // do stuff
                if($.isFunction(callback)){
                    callback.call(this, $(list));
                }
        },

        method2 : function( settings, callback ) { 
            // do stuff
                if($.isFunction(callback)){
                    callback.call(this, $(list));
                }
        },

        method3 : function( settings, callback ) { 
            // do stuff
                if($.isFunction(callback)){
                    callback.call(this, $(list));
                }
        },


};

$.fn.jPlugin = function( method ) {
    if ( methods[method] ) {
        return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } 

    else if ( typeof method === 'object') {
        $.error( 'Expected two (2) parameters: parameter 1 must be the method name to call. Parameter 2 must be an object containing the settings for this method.' );
    } 

    else {
        $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist' );
    }   
};
```

And I'm a bit confused about this line in the jQuery plugin documentation:

```
return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
```

The plugin works as expected id no callback is passed. But how should I do to pass the callback to the correct method if I call the plugin like this?

```
$('#my-div').jPlugin('method1', settings);
```

Should the callback function be part of the settings object or might I adapt the plugin to accept this?

```
$('#my-div').jPlugin('method1', settings, callback);
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: `$('#my-div').jPlugin('method1', settings, callback);` will work with your current plugin code. What exactly do you have problems with?

Comment: I just don't understand completly the "call" piece. I thought the (arguments, 1) refered to the second argument of $('#my-div').jPlugin('method1', settings);,... so "settings". I didn't know if I should add the callback somewhere else.

Comment: I guess, "arguments" itself refers to all the arguments of the calling, so settings and callback, that's it?

Comment: Sorry, too many information at the same time for me,... slice means every element starting from the 2nd one...

Comment: `arguments` is not an array, it is only *array-like*. The `slice` function returns a subarray starting at the index you provide. So `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)` is applying `slice` to `arguments`, therefore treating it like an array. If `arguments` was an array, it would be the same as `arguments.slice(1)`, which means, get all elements from the array from the second element on. It is basically removing the method name and passes all the remaining arguments to your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer in @Felix Kling comments